# Tell Wolfram Alpha that a variable is a natural number

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, wolfram-alpha

How can I tell Wolfram Alpha that some variables are natural numbers, when I want to solve a equation?

An example of what I want to do:

$\binom{n}{k}\cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{x-np}{\sqrt{n \cdot p \cdot (1-p)}}\right)^2}$ solve for $x$ with $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 \lt p \lt 1$.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: i have the same problem, here's an example @Amzoti :
sum_{i=1}^{infinity}(1/2)^i*(1-p)^(i-1) assuming p in ]0,1[

Comment: This works in wolfram alpha (tested now): > solve (x-3/2)(x-2)=0 over the naturals

Answer (score 8):

Just add an "assuming x integer" at the end. I tested it, and it seems to work. (similar to Maple's notation assuming x::integer, I guess)
For natural it doesn't seem to work properly: [assuming x natural](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+gamma%28x%29+assuming+x+natural)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @Skeen Pardon me, but my link seems to work. Funny enough, even assuming x natural works (just click the link)

Comment: I'm getting this: Wolfram|Alpha does not yet know how to respond to your exact query.
The "closest interpretation" is based on lexical and semantic similarity in Wolfram|Alpha's computable knowledge space.

Comment: Can you give a link? As I said, I have no problem with the link in my Answer - it simplifies Gamma(x) to (x+1)! using the assumption that x is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you are trying what it is you are trying to solve. Telling Mathematica that something is an integer has a different syntax depending on what you are trying to do.

Assuming that you are using the "Solve" function, it would look like this:

```
Solve[(x - 3/2) (x - 2)== 0 && x \[Element] Integers]
```

**EDIT.**  After 6 years, the website has changed and this no longer works. However,

```
 Solve (x-3/2)(x-2)=0 for x integer
```

seemed to work, as you can [can see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20(x-3%2F2)(x-2)%3D0%20for%20x%20integer).

Comment: This does not work for wolfram alpha.

Comment: @opa Thank you. After 6 years, the site has changed a lot.

Comment: And how would we specify that all variables in the expression are real?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As dirty as this is, I've used modulus 1 to force numbers to be integers. Combine with a >= 0 restriction and you can reach Natural numbers.

[Example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max((14x%20%2B%2010y%20%2B%2050)%20*%20(1%20%2B%200.05y)),%20x%20%2B%20y%20%3D%204,%20x%20%3E%3D%200,%20y%20%3E%3D%200,%20x%20mod%201%20%3D%200,%20y%20mod%201%20%3D%200&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22max%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22OptimizationWord%22%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Solve[ ..., Element[..., Integers]]

Comment: This does not work for wolfram alpha