# How do I include an integer constraint in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: optimization, integers, computer-algebra-systems, wolfram-alpha

Related question: [Tell Wolfram Alpha that a variable is a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547109)

---

I want to do [the following](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749509/140308) in Wolfram Alpha:

> Minimise
>
> $$z = (y_1-x_1)+(x_2-y_2)+(1/2)(x_3)$$
>
> s.t.
>
> $$0 \le x_1 \le y_1$$
>
> $$y_2 \le x_2 \le 2y_2$$
>
> $$2y_3 \le x_3 \le 3y_3$$
>
> $$y_1+y_2+y_3=1$$
>
> $$y_1, y_2, y_3 \in \{0,1\}$$
>
> $$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$$

It seems pretty long so I kind of converted

> $$0 \le x_1 \le y_1$$
>
> $$y_2 \le x_2 \le 2y_2$$
>
> $$2y_3 \le x_3 \le 3y_3$$
>
> $$y_1, y_2, y_3 \in \{0,1\}$$
>
> $$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$$

into

> $$0 \le x_1 \le y_1 \le 1$$
>
> $$\color{red}{0 \le} y_2 \le x_2 \le 2y_2 \color{red}{\le 2}$$
>
> $$\color{red}{0 \le} 2y_3 \le x_3 \le 3y_3 \color{red}{\le 3}$$
>
> $$\color{red}{y_1, y_2, y_3 \ \text{is an integer}}$$

Anyway, I typed

> minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1

[That works](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20(y1-x1)%2B(x2-y2)%2B(1%2F2)*(x3),%200%20%3C%3D%20x1%20%3C%3D%20y1%20%3C%3D%201,%200%20%3C%3D%20y2%20%3C%3D%20x2%20%3C%3D%202*y2%20%3C%3D2,%200%20%3C%3D%202*y3%20%3C%3D%20x3%20%3C%3D%203*y3%20%3C%3D%203,%20y1%2By2%2By3%3D1) but [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20(y1-x1)%2B(x2-y2)%2B(1%2F2)*(x3),%200%20%3C%3D%20x1%20%3C%3D%20y1%20%3C%3D%201,%200%20%3C%3D%20y2%20%3C%3D%20x2%20%3C%3D%202*y2%20%3C%3D2,%200%20%3C%3D%202*y3%20%3C%3D%20x3%20%3C%3D%203*y3%20%3C%3D%203,%20y1%2By2%2By3%3D1,%20y1%20is%20an%20integer)

> minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1, $\color{red}{\text{y1 is an integer}}$

doesn't work.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

The given constraints on $y_1, y_2, y_3$ are such that there are only three cases:  $$(y_1, y_2, y_3) \in \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}.$$  In each case, two of the three variables $$x_1, x_2, x_3$$ are constrained to $0$ and the resulting function $z$ becomes univariate on the remaining nontrivial variable.

Note that WolframAlpha does not accept/parse the full range of *Mathematica* input syntax.  You could do the requested command with

```
Minimize[{(y1 - x1) + (x2 - y2) + x3/2, 0 <= x1 <= y1 && 
  y2 <= x2 <= 2 y2 && 2 y3 <= x3 <= 3 y3 && y1 + y2 + y3 == 1 &&
  (y1 == 0 || y1 == 1) && (y2 == 0 || y2 == 1) &&
  (y3 == 0 || y3 == 1)}, {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}]
```

which produces

```
{0, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 0, y1 -> 0, y2 -> 1, y3 -> 0}}
```

but there is another minimum for

```
{0, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, y1 -> 1, y2 -> 0, y3 -> 0}}
```

Comment: Is x2 really 2 and not 1? The min value is supposed to be zero. Anyway thanks heropup. Ill try these out later. That's really the wolframalpha code and not mathematica code?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749509/140308

Comment: @BCLC I mistyped your function $z$.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: thanks ^-^ I'll check it out later.

Comment: heropup, oh that's indeed the mathematica code? so WA could read what I typed above had it more space?

Answer (score 0):

You specified in your query that y1,y2,y3 are all positive definite. y1+y2+y3=1 and y3 is and integer.

Or y1,y2 =0 and y3 =1, this forces x1,x2 = 0, 2 <= x3 <= 3

z reaches its minimum under this condition at x3 =2, z=1

WA is confused because of the length of the query. Appending any additional argument to the end of

minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1

will confuse WA, such as

minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1,y3=1

minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1,y2=0

minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1,y1=0

all will confuse WA

Comment: where did i say that yi's are all positive?

Comment: 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, This part implies everything is positive.

Comment: Why can't some be zero?

Comment: I edited my post to show the case where some are zero. Is that not visible (i'm new to this forum)?

Comment: you said my constraints make all the yi's positive. Yet the yi's can be zero. Soooo...?

Comment: you're right i was being sloppy. I should have said Positive Definite. Or simply not negative.

Comment: so nonnegative. Why is this something that would WA confused?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39755/discussion-between-shai-horowitz-and-bclc).

Comment: WA is confused because of the length of the query. Appending any additional argument to the end of

minimize (y1-x1)+(x2-y2)+(1/2)*(x3), 0 <= x1 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= x2 <= 2*y2 <=2, 0 <= 2*y3 <= x3 <= 3*y3 <= 3, y1+y2+y3=1

will confuse WA