# How can I restrict a variable to a given domain in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, computer-algebra-systems

Ever since I began using Wolfram Alpha for quick online calculations I have had trouble specifying the domain of my variables. Note that I have already read the related MSO question "*[Tell Wolfram Alpha that a variable is a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547109/tell-wolfram-alpha-that-a-variable-is-a-natural-number)*", but that did not help.

Let's take a minimal simple example: expanding the binomial coefficient $2n \choose n$. Of course, depending on $n$  we have vastly different results. For instance, the formula ${\displaystyle {\binom {n}{k}}={\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}}}$ is only valid for positive integers $n$ and $k$, while ${n \choose k}={\frac {\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (k+1)\Gamma (n-k+1)}}$ is valid for complex $n$ and $k$. Naturally, in such a simple case there is no real difference, but in more complex queries there is.

If we try "*[Expand (2n choose n)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(2n%20choose%20n))*" with Alpha, we will not get the desired result if we want $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, following several pieces of advice found commonly in other forums, we try the following, without success:

- "*[Expand (2n choose n), assuming n integer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(2n%20choose%20n),%20assuming%20n%20integer)*" gives "**closest Wolfram|Alpha interpretation: choose assuming integer**",
- "*[Expand (2n choose n), for n integer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(2n%20choose%20n),%20for%20n%20integer)*" gives "**closest Wolfram|Alpha interpretation: expand (2n n), n**",
- "*[Expand (2n choose n), for integer n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(2n%20choose%20n),%20for%20integer%20n)*" gives "**closest Wolfram|Alpha interpretation: expand (2n n)**",
- and so forth with many variations of the above.

This same scenario arises in many situations where I need Alpha to understand that my variable is in a certain domain. I know Alpha understands Mathematica syntax to some extent, but I do not want to start mixing Alpha and Mathematica syntax as it quickly becomes confusing for larger inputs. Moreover, Alpha was *designed* to process more "human" inputs.

So is there any way of telling Alpha that my variable is part of a given domain in a simple way?

Comment: I would rather just use Mathematica syntax. In this way you can also run your code in Mathematica, not just on WolframAlpha.