# How to make Wolfram Alpha give me a range of possible answers for an equation if the subject is assumed to be an integer?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am trying to use Wolfram Alpha, and I am trying to get it to give me a range of possible answers for *y=(391-x)/x*, if y was an integer. However, there are two problems I face with this. The first is that I'm not sure as to how to tell WA that I want both my pronumerals to be an integers. I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547109/tell-wolfram-alpha-that-a-variable-is-a-natural-number) on how to do it but it seems to be outdated.

My second problem is that even if WA know that  both *x* and *y* are positive  integers, how would I tell it to give me a set of possible values for *x* and *y* in order to satisfy the equation?

If anyone can help me, please give me an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you mean Wolfram Alpha and not Wolfram Mathematica? Enforcing assumptions on equations is problematic on the web one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  `solve y=(391-x)/x over the integers`

Comment: Well, thanks! This worked!